# Problem when bevelling a cross

Tags: modifiers, bevel

To bevel a cross, I started from a cube and extruded four of it's faces along the X and Z axis. I have defined four vertex group, each containing the four vertex located at the end of each branch.

Then, I have added bevel modifiers and applied them to my four vertex groups. They work perfectly, except the bevel associated with the vertex group containing the four left hand vertex.
Changing the modifiers order doesn't make any change.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this strange behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices, it makes the bevel fail, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*